# sqlite android database information manipulation

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have created a database in android studio, and I can access the information through a .db file where i can see all the information typed in by the user in different custom made columns.

If we had a scenario where i was asked to type in a specific string that is assigned to a column in the database, and that my application return a FALSE or a POSITIVE depending on if I was able to provide it with the correct information.

For Example:

I have created a database file in android studio with 2 columns.
One of the columns is (ID) and the other one is (NAME) that is storing the information for NAME (a name in the persons school).

Later in the application the user is asked to type in the name of any student in the school, and if the user is providing the application with correct information, we can proceed, else we must try again. (So here is basically where we would have to match the information that we are typing in, to the information stored in our database).

I am a beginner. I will share my code with you, and ask for suggestions on how to start working on this problem.

```
//The DatabaseHelper class I am working on right now

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "miris.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "miris_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "id";
    public static final String COL_2 = "name";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
        AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
        {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

        public boolean insertData (String name) 
            {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
            long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
            if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check info recieved from the info alredy stored in database before inserting it in database

For eg.

```
     public boolean insertData (String name) 
     {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String cols[]={COL_1,COL_2};

        Cursor c=db.query(TABLE_NAME, cols,COL_2+"=?",new String[]{""+name}, null, null, null);
        if(c.getCount()>0){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
            long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
            if(result == -1)
                return false;
            else
                return true;

        }

        }
```

Comment: If we just focus on this part: Cursor c=db.query(TABLE_NAME, cols,COL_2+"=?",new String[]{""+name}, null, null, null);                                                -                                                                                                                      I have tried to read about cursor query, but I am having difficulties understanding this part. What exactly is it doing here?